# How to prevent continuous clicks from end-users when submitting data?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I research Rxjs with exhaustMap but it is higher-order observable.
My case just simple add a row to db.
is there any other way since i don't use higher-order

Comment: You can use `exhaustMap` before saving to DB, Its an operator, You can share your code

Comment: Please show your code :-)

Comment: Once it is submitted, you can disable the button and once the response is back(success/error) you can decide to enable it again.

Answer (score 2):

The higher order operator `exhaustMap` will ignore any emitted values from source until inner observable completes.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap

In your case you can do such:

```js
const btnClicks$ = fromEvent(addRowBtn, 'click')

btnClicks$.pipe(
  exhaustMap((_) => {
    //clear form here for example to make sure the user will not send the same data again.
    return callToApi(formData)
  })
  // Any click event will simply be ignored until you get a response from api.
).subscribe()
```

Take note here that `exhaustMap` only works with observables, if your callToApi() function return a promise you can wrap it with defer() like so:

```js
const btnClicks$ = fromEvent(addRowBtn, 'click')

const addRowApi = defer(() => callToApi(formData)) // this returns an observable that exhaustMap can subscribe to.

btnClicks$.pipe(
  exhaustMap((_) => {
    //clear form here for example to make sure the user will not send the same data again from example
    return addRowApi()
  })
  // Any click event will simply be ignored until you get a response from api.
).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after `throttleTime`.

`throttleTime` emits a value from the source Observable, then ignores subsequent source values for duration milliseconds, then repeats this process.

Here's an example:

```ts
const clicks$ = fromEvent(startBtn, 'click');

function dataBaseApi(dataRow): Observable<ResponseType>{
  return addDataToRow(dbClient, dataRow);
}

clicks$.pipe(
  throttleTime(2000),
  map(clickToData),
  concatMap(dataBaseApi)
).subscribe();
```